# dynamic change timing of angular animation

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to create an animation of a circle that grows in two steps and then shrinks.

I want to allow the user to change the time it takes for each step. I'm using Angular and the new AnimationBuilder class to try and assign the new animations timings..but to no vail. It seems like the first definition of the animation trigger won't change.

I'm trying to re-create the animation trigger with the animation builder and assign it to the circle..but it doesn't seem to work

You can check a working example of the code in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HreL6qZ67uhnOXxrdJjN?p=preview)

```
const myAnimation = this.animBuilder.build(
  [
    transition('inactive => firstStep', animate(this.timingBounds.lower)),
    transition('firstStep => secondStep', animate(this.timingBounds.upper - 
        this.timingBounds.lower)),
    transition('secondStep => inactive', animate(this.timingTotal - 
        this.timingBounds.upper))
  ]
);

this.currentAnimationPlayer = myAnimation.create(this.circle.nativeElement);
```

Am I doing something awfully wrong? do you guys think this is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr for your case? Do you call `this.currentAnimationPlayer.play()` after this code?

Comment: I have provided a plunkr. The animation work with triggers so it should play different parts of the animation depending on the value of the trigger variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I did is to ditch the animation system and animate it myself by using the requestAnimationFrame function and modifying the circle accordingly.

Comment: Could you post an example to clarify this answer?